# How should I return data

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to understand and implement simple app. I've got two express servers, first is only sending plain object and the second is fetching it.
Inside the second app I want to build a class - Loader, that will provide fetch and get (data) methods.

```
class Loader{
constructor(){
    this.data = {data:"some data"}
}

async fetchData(){
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/data");
    if(res) {
        this.data = res.data
        console.log(this.data)
        return res.data
    }
}

getData(){
    return this.data
}

async getFetchedData(){
    await this.fetchData();
    console.log(this.data)
    this.getData();
}
}
```

But actually it doesn't work the way I wanted it. I'd like to implement method that will return fetched object.

```
const testLoader = new Loader();
testLoader.getFetchedData();
const testVar = testLoader.getData();
console.log("test", testVar)
```

The output is:

```
test { data: 'some data' }
data from fetchData { data: 'test data after fetching' }
data from getFetchedData { data: 'test data after fetching' }
```

And I understand - getData is sync and the rest methods are async, so that's the order of perform. But how do I need to rewrite code to receive method that will return the fetched object?

Comment: You shouldn't use `getData` at all. Just write `const testVar = await testLoader.getFetchedData();`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Please be more specific. How does it not work, what does fail, what's the error message?

Comment: I'm sorry. Your solution gives me "await is only valid in async function".

Comment: Uh, sure, any code with `await` must be wrapped in an `async` function, I just omitted that part for brevity. It seemed you already knew how to use these. In case you can't or don't want to use them, the equivalent would be `testLoader.getFetchedData().then(testVar => { console.log("test", testVar); … });`

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to await for any async methods to complete (or then-chain them) wherever you use them.

```
const testLoader = new Loader();
await testLoader.fetchData();
const testVar = testLoader.getData();
console.log("test", testVar)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try some code i made

```js
class Loader{
  constructor(){
      this.data = {data:"some data"}
  }
  async fetchData(){
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/data");
      this.data = res.data
  }
  getData(){
      return this.data
  }
  async getFetchedData(){
      await this.fetchData();
      console.log(this.data)
      return this.getData();
  }
}

// 1
const exec = async () => {
  try {
    const loader = new Loader()
    await loader.fetchData()
    console.log(loader.getData())
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("ERROR", e)
  }
}
exec()


// 2
const exec = async () => {
  try {
    const loader = new Loader()
    const data = await loader.getFetchedData()
    console.log(data)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("ERROR", e)
  }
}
exec()


// 3
const loader = new Loader()
loader.fetchData().then(() => {
  console.log(loader.getData())
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log("ERROR", e)
})


// 4
const loader = new Loader()
loader.getFetchedData().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log("ERROR", e)
})
```